# okay so I created this code to create a GUI but i need to add buttons and when ever i try it creates a new window. what should I do?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

this is my code so far o cant add buttons with out it creating more windows

////////

```
#import tkinter
import tkinter
#import tkmessagebox(buttons)
from tkinter import *
#create a new window
window = tkinter.Tk()
#title <------ put it before .mainloop
window.title("yeahh boiiii")
#window size
window.geometry("500x500")
#set a window icon
window.iconbitmap('N:\downloads\icon.ico.ico')#<---- 8bit file name

master = Tk()

def callback():
print ("click!")


b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()


#draws the window
window.mainloop()
```

////////

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you create 2 instances of `Tk()`. This is a bad idea, and you don't need to do it since you can make your button a child of the `window` object:

```
# Import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
# Create a new window
window = tk.Tk()
# Title <------ put it before .mainloop
window.title("yeahh boiiii")
# Window size
window.geometry("500x500")
# Set a window icon
window.iconbitmap('N:\downloads\icon.ico.ico') #<---- 8bit file name

def callback():
    print ("click!")

b = tk.Button(window, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

# Draw the window
window.mainloop()
```

I also rewrote your `tkinter` import, because you were importing it twice...